# Docker compose not available on docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

**Question 1**: I am new to docker swarm, I created a docker swarm cluster on my local machine and SSH in to it. To my surprise docker-compose was NOT installed inside the manager node. Is that normal ? Is there any workaround to get the docker compose up and running on swarm manager node ?

**Question 2**: how do I manage to get all my code inside manager node. Let’s say I have my source code on a director. If I want to move that inside my docker swarm manager node. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common for `docker-compose` to not be installed on servers compared to docker-desktop-clients which come bundled with `docker-compose` and other tools.
You  have to install it to use it on your local machine. https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Although you can use your installation of `docker-compose` to work against the docker-daemon on your local machine by setting `DOCKER_HOST`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables

You can copy your source-code onto your local-machine via `scp` https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/

But you would rather build images and deploy onto your local-machine.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!